# How to install wireless antenna TP-LINK TL-WN722N?

Tags: wireless, drivers, 9.04

TP-LINK TL-WN722N is a usb antenna for wireless network.

The antenna cames with a cd for windows (and works just fine), but how can I install it on Ubuntu? It's not recognizing alone.

Comment: execute `lsusb` in a terminal and udpate your post with this information of this command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok good news and bad news the good news is in most cases you dont actually need to install drivers for things in Ubuntu because the Linux kernel has a lot of drivers built in, the only cases where you may need to install drivers are for graphics cards and network cards(not so much).

So the bad news is if you have the card installed fine and Ubuntu itself doesnt offer the driver to you and its not recognizing it, then we dont have the driver. Your best hope is to try a later release of Ubuntu and hope someone added the driver for your card. Its a real pain but it doesnt happen to a lot of people in recent times.

So in short you'll more than likely have to wait and see or ask the company who make the card if they can make the driver.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need the compat-wireless drivers and relevant patches. Google "ar9170 driver" for all the necessary links(don't remember off the top). I have this working great in Ubuntu 10.10 with the aircrack-ng suite and WiFite. Make sure you dl compat- wireless and unpack 1st. Then dl patches(including "negative-minus-one-maxim") to the same directory. The rest is easy as per the links.
Hope this helps. Worth going through as this is the best adapter I've found when working properly.
stamphead1