# TP LINK WN722n not working on ubuntu 14.02

Tags: wireless, drivers

I'm new to ubuntu, so I'm learning. I have hp 655 with amd processor. I had win 7, and i bought tp link wn722n for better wifi signal. Now I can't use it, because I use Ubuntu and don't know how to install drivers. I tried this steps [ubuntu questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21238/how-to-install-wireless-antenna-tp-link-tl-wn722n?rq=1) but that didn't help. Can anybody help me?
The results are:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: lsusb Thanks.

Comment: Yes, i tried that steps, but that just not works for me. I have wi fi card on laptop, but external dont work. I dont have any user interface, or something @P.-H.Lin

Comment: Are you saying that you do not see the Network Manager icon at the top right? http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Screenshot-2.png

Comment: I see Network Manager, but now i use onboard wi fi. It have very poor signal. When i stick tp link, signal should be stronger, but nothing happens. Or i should do something more to start using tp link? @chili555

Comment: We may be able to troubleshoot the internal card. If not, we ought to blacklist its driver so we have no conflicts. What is it? lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: I get this result :Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:3290] @chili555

Comment: In case that dont work, how can i make Ralink driver work again? Thanks a lot on your help :) @chili555

Comment: I try step 2 and i got this massages :WARNING: Error inserting ath9k_hw (/lib/modules/3.2.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko): Invalid argument
WARNING: Error inserting ath9k_common (/lib/modules/3.2.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko): Invalid argument
WARNING: Error inserting mac80211 (/lib/modules/3.2.0-32-generic/updates/dkms/mac80211.ko): Invalid argument
FATAL: Error inserting ath9k_htc (/lib/modules/3.2.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_htc.ko): Invalid argument

Comment: Please see my edit below.

Comment: that didnt work too... I follow that steps and i got error massages. When i do that, I can see network manager, but no network at all (tp link inserted). Guess no hope for me :/ @chili555

Comment: It might be helpful to see the errors.

Comment: These are the errors : http://postimg.org/image/63e1vqxbl/ @chili555

Comment: @Flakutin It appears that you installed some other conflicting driver package that is interfering. We will need to remove it. Do you recall? Does this help us? history | grep backport Thanks,

Comment: When I do that, i get this massage :  17  wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.16/backports-3.16-1.tar.gz
   18  tar xvfz backports-3.16-1.tar.gz
   19  cd backports-3.16-1
   29  tar xvfz backports-3.16-1.tar.gz
   30  cd backports-3.16-1
   63  history | grep backport @chili555

Comment: Please see my edit in a few moments.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you blacklist the quirky Realtek 3290:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rt2800pci"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r rt2800pci
exit
```

Your TP Link uses the driver ath9k_htc. Let's load it and see if there are any errors:

```
sudo modprobe ath9k_htc
dmesg | grep ath
iwconfig
```

In order to get ath9k_htc to work correctly, let's remove backports. Please do:

```
cd ~
ls | grep back
```

The *ls* command will verify that we are in the correct directory. If the command returns: backports-3.16-1, then let's remove it:

```
cd backports-3.16-1
sudo make uninstall
sudo depmod -a
```

Reboot and show us:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

The driver ath9k_htc should load without any complaint.